# Horizontal image view gallery

Tags: android

i am trying to built custom horizontal scroll view gallery rather than using the gallery widget in android b/c it is deprecated in api 16.I am able to add images in scroll view but how i change the larger image view when user clicks on respective thumbnails of image in horizontal scroll view.Here is code

```
private Integer[] Imgid = {
        R.drawable.monk1,
        R.drawable.mon2,
        R.drawable.mon3,
};

LinearLayout linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Linear);

for(x=0;x<15;x++) {
    Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),Imgid[x]);

    int width = bitmapOrg.getWidth();
    int height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();
    int newWidth = 200;
    int newHeight = 200;

    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    matrix.postRotate(0);

    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0,
                  width, height, matrix, true);
    BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),resizedBitmap);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setPadding(2, 0, 9, 5);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(bmd);
    imageView.setTag(x);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[]); // large imageview
        }
    });

    linearLayout1.addView(imageView);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do something like this

you need to open an intent to view an image as follows:

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.name/" + R.drawable.monk1,)
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set a layout param to the imageview when doing on click?

Comment: Do you want to increase the size of the imageview? Or you want to preview the image?